# Compare 2 JSON Arrays with the same keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

2 different JSON arrays with same keys like below:

Array 1:

```
{ "fruit1" : "Apple", "fruit2" : "Banana", "fruit3" : "Grapes" }
```

Array 2:

```
{ "fruit1" : "First Fruit", "fruit2" : "Second Fruit", "fruit3" : "Third Fruit" }
```

As you can see, 2 arrays that have same keys but different values, now what i wanted is that i wanted the result or the display to be like this:

```
First Fruit is Apple
Second Fruit is Banana
Third Fruit is Grapes
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str1 = '{ "fruit1" : "Apple", "fruit2" : "Banana", "fruit3" : "Grapes" }';
$str2 = '{ "fruit1" : "First Fruit", "fruit2" : "Second Fruit", "fruit3" : "Third Fruit" }';

$array1 = json_decode($str1);
$array2 = json_decode($str2);

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($array2[$key]) {
        echo $value . " is " . $array2[$key];
    } else {
        echo $value . " has no match in array2.";
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea is to convert the JSON *strings* (there's no such thing as a JSON array) to associative arrays, then go through the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

```
$array1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$array2 = json_decode($json2, true);

foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
  if (isset($array2[$key])) {
    echo $array1[$key],' is ',$array2[$key];
    echo PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```